# How do you copy a worksheet as an Image and paste it into a specific cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

The Situation - I'm designing a method to pass down information from shift to shift. It needs to be rigid enough to stay standardized but flexible enough that  people can explain the myriad situations that occur. My idea is that they fill out their own worksheet and hit a save button that gathers this information into a centralized worksheet that shows all areas.

The issue - I can't figure out how to save the worksheet and place it into the combined pass down, without making the combined pass down look atrocious.

Attempted solution - I thought making the worksheet(filled out by employee) save itself as an image and paste to the combined worksheet but I'm having trouble Making it auto size the cell to fit the image.

Ideal Solution - Making the cell size itself to fit the image automatically.

I'm open for ideas on how to handle this differently. I'm fairly new to excel and most likely not aware of all the options available.

CURRENT CODE:

```
Sub Save()
Worksheets("Leads").Range("A1:G14").CopyPicture
    Worksheets("Combined").Activate
    Worksheets("Combined").Paste
    CenterMe ActiveSheet.Shapes(1), Range("C6:D6")
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this programmatically? If yes, can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53091802/edit) to give us the code you have so far? If no, then this question is better suited to [Superuser](https://superuser.com)

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I will update the question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way to paste the picture in the worksheet.

The final code I got is :

```
Sub Save()
Worksheets("Leads").Range("A1:G14").CopyPicture
Worksheets("Combined").Activate
Worksheets("Combined").Paste Destination:=Worksheets("Combined").Range("C6:D6")
'So the image will be pasted at the destination range given
'You may also add a cell address instead of cell range
End Sub
```

Source - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.paste

Hope this helps !

Comment: It does! Thank you very much.